# Multiple and ors in if statement bash

Tags: unix

Hi i am working on somoething , i need to create a if statement which will take multiple variables in '&&' and '||' combination . for now i am trying to this this simple task but i am getting errors 'Command not found'. i want to first && two counts than || it with a flag i set in my code. following is the code i am trying

```
if [[$pcount -eq 0 ] && [$ucount -eq 0]] ||  [test $flag -eq 1]
then 
do my stuff 
else 
exit 1
fi
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't nest `[ ... ]` because `[` is a shell command, not a separate syntactic construct. In Bash, you can use the `[[ ... ]]` syntactic construct which does support nesting, and in portable `sh` you can use the `( ... )` parentheses for precedence:

```
if ([ $pcount -eq 0 ] && [ $ucount -eq 0 ]) ||  [ $flag -eq 1 ]
```

Additional remarks:

- `[test condition]` doesn't make sense, since the `[` operator is already an alias for `test`. Write either `[ condition ]` or `test condition`.
- Leave a space before `[` and the test, otherwise `sh` won't recognize the `[` as a command name. `[` is a command like any other and is not associated with special parsing rules.

Comment: Thank you for such a extensive answer

Comment: Note that Shellcheck recommends `{ ..; }` instead of `(..)` to avoid subshell overhead:
https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2235

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you can do it like this:

```
if [[ ( $pcount == 0  &&  $ucount == 0 ) || ( $flag == 1 ) ]]
then
    echo "do stuff"
fi
```

Alternatively:

```
if [ "$pcount" -eq 0 -a "$ucount" -eq 0 ] || [ "$flag" -eq 1 ]
then
     echo "do stuff"
fi
```

But, I would recommend the first approach.